# C# DropDownList default values

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I am working with a ascx.cs backend page to try and use four different filters "dropdowns" when selecting a report with parameters. Currently my filers and dropdown lists are working and the parameters are passing and returning back the correct report.

However my values for the drop down lists are generated from the most recent values in a database table, namely month and year.

(eg. year - 2014)
(eg. month - March)

My tables in the database only add each month as they happen so currently (today= 2014-06-10)
therefore to date i have the first few months of 2014.

So to my problem. I am trying to display the most recent values as default. For example in the "year" dropdown that would be 2014 and for the "month" drop down it would be last month.

I also must note that each of my four drop down filters has an autopostback Onselectedchange

example (year)

```
dropdown_year.Items.Clear();
        dropdown_year.Items.Add(new ListItem("Select a year...", "0"));
```

this is within the backend

in the front end things look like this

```
<div class="field">
                        <div class="field-left">
                            <label for="dropdown_year" runat="server">Year</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="field-right">
                            <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="dropdown_year" OnSelectedIndexChanged="dropdown_year_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:DropDownList>
                            <span id="dropdown_year_error" class="error-message" runat="server"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

can anyone suggest how i might be able to get the most recent values?

Answer (score 0):

Once all items are added to particular list in code behind set selected index to be the last one like that:

```
dropdown_year.SelectedIndex = dropdown_year.Items.Count - 1;
```

It depends on how items are sorted when you get them from database. You can sort them descending and then just select first one. If they sorted ascending do as in example above.